# Bash: wget in spider mode outputs nothing

Tags: bash, wget

Having checked examples on this page, i tried the below

```
 wget -q --spider http://a.b.c
```

But nothing is outputted to file or to STDOUT

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the output, remove the `-q` option (quiet mode).
With this option, wget does not output anything, as per the manpage:

> -q
>
> --quiet
>
> Turn off Wget's output.

BTW even with the output disabled, you can still determine what was the outcome. Just check the exit code of the wget command.
Example:

Non-existing file:

```
$ wget --spider http://1.2.3.4/non.existing.file
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2018-10-01 11:57:13--  http://1.2.3.4/non.existing.file
Connecting to 1.2.3.4:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!

$ echo $?
8
```

Existing file:

```
$ wget --spider http://1.2.3.4/existing.file
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2018-10-01 12:04:17--  http://1.2.3.4/existing.file
Connecting to 1.2.3.4:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 10701 (10K) [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.

$ echo $?
0
```